# Select a tag with href="#" and unwrap parent li

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have [navgoco](https://github.com/tefra/navgoco) installed on a website I'm developing. I'm new to jQuery. Navgoco is working great to create some toggles on an unordered list for a side menu.

Here's the issue. Navgoco makes every parent item into a toggle. So, even if a toggle has a link other than a hash (#) and couldn't possibly work as a toggle, it still closes its child items.

I'm curious if I can unwrap a parent item from a child item. Something like this (except this isn't working for me). This would detect urls that don't go anywhere (urls with a hash) and unwrap the parent li so it is not made into a toggle menu.

```
$("ul > li > a[href='#']").parent().unwrap();
```

Additionally, I would love to separate out the link and the toggle. So the a tag can go to a page link, but the toggle goes elsewhere. Like this:

[icon] MENU ITEM

Where the :before (icon) would be a toggle link to open lis below the menu item, and the menu item itself could link to a page.

See how they handle the menu here on the left of the page?
http://sevenspark.com/docs/shiftnav-setup

Maybe I need a solution other than navgoco. Any thoughts?

Comment: So the parent is an li? How do you unwrap the contents when it is in a list?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery UI Accordion and a little `$` jquery usage for this purpose. This can also help you add more tool icon/buttons on the header for other functionalities if need be. Here is a sample on what you want if interested:

http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/mAgmJR

You can also do alot more to customize it's behavior and design.

https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Hope this helps.